# Java application not continuing after establishing a socket with the server

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am trying to get my Java application to communicate with a lightweight Ruby server that I have written. It is running on my LAN, and whenever I try to run the application, it does not proceed any further than the line that establishes the socket with the server and hangs. I am not getting any stack traces and all permissions needed are assigned in the security policy. Any ideas?

This is a brand new server instance and no errors are occurring on the server-end.

```java
// Start the server listener
ServerListener listener = new ServerListener();
listener.start();

Logging logging = new Logging();
logging.addEntry(EntryType.SUCCESS, "Started the server listener.");

// Send a network request to the server
// Hangs here
try {
   // Initialize the socket and output stream
   Socket socket = new Socket("ip", port);
   socket.setSoTimeout(3000);
   DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

   // Write the computer name
   out.writeUTF(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
   out.flush();

   // Close the streams
   out.close();
   socket.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I expected the application to continue after it has connected to the server, sent the message and closed all of the sockets/output streams, but it just hangs as soon as it establishes a socket connection to the server.

Comment: What's that `ServerListener` business about?

Comment: Oh, that's just another thread that listens for messages from the server.

Comment: So you are saying that the call to `new Socket("ip", port);` blocks indefinitely?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Since this _just another thread that listens for messages from the server_ must make its own connection to the server, the question arises whether your _lightweight Ruby server_ is prepared to concurrently serve multiple connections.